# Extend Cypress.io with namespace instead of a command

Tags: cypress

so I can extend the `cy.` with any command, i.e. `cy.doSomethingAwesome()`, but I want to namespace them, like: `cy.product.get()`

I don't see in the docs how to do that, is that even possible?

I know I can do `cy.product().get()` and have the `.product` command return an object with functions, but I'm wondering if there a more elegant way of namespacing this.

Comment: if its just for organization reasons, why not just create a class product and product.get() uses cypress to do whatever

Comment: lol I feel kinda dumb not thinking about this. Haven't tried it yet but don't see a reason it won't work